# Make a Bash script echo executed commands

Tags: bash

I put together a bunch of alias commands in a folder.  Mainly ssh, so instead of having to type...

```
ssh [user]@[server]
```

...ten times a day, I can just type...

```
server
```

...and the alias script fires.  The script is simply the command...

```
ssh [user]@[server]
```

This is all working fine, but I was wondering if there was a way in Bash where instead of firing the ssh command quietly, it would display the command that is being executed?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can [debug the script](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html) with `-x`, which will echo the commands and arguments.

```
bash -x script.sh
```

You can do this for specific portions of the file, too (from section 2.3.2 linked above):

```
set -x          # activate debugging from here
ssh user@example.com ...
set +x          # stop debugging from here
```

The output from `-x` might be a bit too verbose for what you're looking for, though, since it's meant for debugging (and not logging).

You might be better off just writing out your own `echo` statements - that'd give you full control over the output.

Comment: that kinda defeats the purpose of the alias.  unless someone has another idea, i will just add an echo for the command above the actual command and see how that works.

Comment: @scphantm - Yeah, it's really not meant for logging, either - moreso it's for debugging. But it does the job. There's likely a better solution. Adding your own `echo` statements would probably be the best; you'd have full control over the logging, then. I've incorporated that into my answer.

Answer (score 18):

Put "-x" at the top of your script instead of on the command line:

#### File *server*

```
#!/bin/bash -x
ssh user@server
```

#### Execution

```
./server
```

results in:

```
+ ssh user@server
user@server's password: ^C
```

Comment: I never knew you could put those parameters on the shebang line, I always used `set -x` on a separate line, this is much nicer looking.

Answer (score 3):

The existing answers answer the question in the title. But I'd like to address the underlying problem of more efficiently SSH-ing to a server.

Rather than create a bunch of bash script aliases, the arguably better way to do this is with an [`ssh_config`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) file.

If you put this in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host deadpool
    Hostname abcdefghijklmnop.my.verbose.hosting-service.com
    User scphantm
    # Lots of other useful options here
```

Then, rather than typing this:

```
$ ssh scphantm@abcdefghijklmnop.my.verbose.hosting-service.com
```

You can do this:

```
$ ssh deadpool
```

or

```
$ scp deadpool:/var/log/apache/access.log access_logs.txt
```

or

```
$ any_other_ssh-based_command deadpool
```

Config file reference:

> **`Host`**
> Restricts the following declarations (up to the next `Host` keyword) to be only for those hosts that match one of the patterns given after the keyword.

> **`HostName`**
> Specifies the real host name to log into. This can be used to specify nicknames or abbreviations for hosts. The default is the name given on the command line. Numeric IP addresses are also permitted (both on the command line and in `HostName` specifications).

> **`User`**
> Specifies the user to log in as. This can be useful when a different user name is used on different machines. This saves the trouble of having to remember to give the user name on the command line.